# Showing Count in a Join situation in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query which is working just as great as i want it to. But i would like to add a count column

```
sqlCustomerDetails = "Select Region,sum(debitamount) as Sales from (select region,debitamount from tblcustomerdetails where dateoftrans between '" & DateFrom & "' and '" & DateTo & "' and region like'%" & Me.txtRegion.Text & "%'" & _
        " union all select region,debitamount from tblupcustomerdetails where dateoftrans between '" & DateFrom & "' and '" & DateTo & "' and region like'%" & Me.txtRegion.Text & "%') t group by region order by sales desc"
```

Ok, in the tblcustomerdetails and tblupcustomerdetails tables there is a column "CustomerName".

At the moment the results shown is as follows.

```
Region - Sales

UK - 100,000

NY - 200,000

Germany - 500,000
```

and so on, i would like to add a third column which would look like this

```
Region - Sales - CustomerCount

UK - 100,000 - 10

NY - 200,000 - 20

Germany - 500,000 - 5
```

The tblcustomerdetails and tblupcustomerdetails will all have the following columns

```
CustomerName, Region, DebitAmount, DateOfTrans.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `CustomerName` to the inner UNION query

```
select  region, debitamount, CustomerName
from    tblcustomerdetails

union all

select  region, debitamount, CustomerName
from    tblupcustomerdetails
```

at the outer query

```
Select Region, sum(debitamount) as Sales, COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerName) as CustomerCount
```

Don't change the `GROUP BY`

```
group by region
```

Comment: i tried this, but this ungroups the region, so all the customer counts become 1.

Comment: My bad. Your query is rather hard to read as it is not formatted in readable form. Anyway don't change the `GROUP BY`

Comment: Thank you very much mate, working charms. Much appreciated.